# Why VIM's (jk) navigate file line instead of screen line?

Tags: vim, key-bindings

Why VIM set the default line navigation (jk) to navigate file line instead of screen line. Is there any use-case when this behavior is desirable?

Comment: Is this a technical question or an attempt to start a rant?

Comment: neither. I was just wondering. I used gvim a lot in writing program as well as managing several daily lists I got (finance, shopping list, etc) which never need wrapping lines. However, recently I tried to use gvim in creating articles and I started to notice the behavior of jk and the above question just pop off in my head. But if the question was too vulnerable to start flames, I guess I will just kill my curiosity about this.

Comment: I can see how debate can result from this, but this question doesn't have to turn into a flamefest.  My take on this is that the standard old-school text format consists of relatively short lines with newlines at the end.  There are many commands that reformat text by adding and removing newline characters.  In that context, moving by screen lines doesn't make sense.  Also, it's harder to implement.  Another aspect is that you need soft word wrap (where the long line is wrapped at word boundaries) before moving by screen lines makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the behavior by adding these to your .vimrc:

```
nnoremap j gj
nnoremap k gk
```

Comment: I already remapped jk keys for navigating screen line in visual and normal mode. However, I still doesn't get my answer for the question. Now I wonder how many vim user (who use vim to create lengthy articles) remap the jk keys. Anyway, thanks MrException (:

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is a desirable case particularly for blockwise selection and alignment of lines.

I particularly appreciate j and k to be consistent, which means ‘move to next file line, same column’.

Just consider that you can do this: by using CTRL-V and then j$.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZIOY.png]

Of course this is a completely random example and I never had any error accessing SO.